# How to read a wave file block by block in python (compatible with numpy array)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikits

Instead of loading the entire wave file, I want to read a wave file block by block in python (compatible with numpy array). That is, only a portion of wave file is to be loaded into the numpy array at a time. I am aware of scipy.io.wavfile.read(somefile) and  scikits.audiolab.wavread(filename). But they do not support blockwise. Entire wavefile is loaded. The problem is when the wave file size is very large, a lot of memory is used.

Comment: Most wav files don't use blocks, so it's unclear to me exactly what you mean.  Regardless, this isn't really a well posed question for SO.  It's better to try something first yourself, not just ask for people here to do it for you.  Additionally, this is basically asking for a tool recommendation to do some task, and that's also off topic for SO.

Comment: @tom10 Thanks for your comment. I have modified my question. I hope, it is better now.

Comment: As I already mentioned, it would help if you posted some effort towards this. But how about just using scipy.io.wavefile.read( , mmap=True) if memory use is the issue?

Comment: To add to what @tom10 said, memory mapping is probably your best solution. I don't know the specifics of the wave format but if you want to hold it in a single numpy array without reading it all in at once, mmap is your only choice. Note that memory maps will show a large memory usage in the virtual address space, but its not necessarily loading/using all of that space at once.

Comment: What I am looking for is a equivalent for Wave_read.readframes(n) in Wave package. (Reads and returns at most n frames of audio, as a string of bytes). I do not find similar one using numpy or scikits. I have read that it is better to work with numpy datatypes. That is why, I am looking for that.

Comment: Then I would suggest opening the file in binary mode `open(fn, 'rb')` and reading a number of bytes and then put those bytes in to a numpy array with your custom dtype. This way you are only reading the parts that you need. There is no way in numpy (other than memmap) to allocate an array from a file, but only load the parts you need. Numpy arrays don't work like that.

Comment: @daveydave400 this comment is also a valuable info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying PySoundFile?
According to the [site](https://github.com/bastibe/PySoundFile):

*Sound files can also be read in short, optionally overlapping blocks. For example, this calculates the signal level for each block of a long file:*

```
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf

rms = [np.sqrt(np.mean(block**2)) for block in
sf.blocks('myfile.wav', blocksize=1024, overlap=512)]
```

I hope this helps.